# Android HttpPost doesn't send data

Tags: php, android, post, http-post

I'm working with HttpPost to request a code from my server but it was working fine until I add an other parameter. This is my code:

```
private String getShareCode(String t, String d, String lat, String lng) {
    String respTxt; 
    try{
        HttpClient dbClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost actionPost = new HttpPost(Config.URL_CODE);

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("t",t));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("d",d));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",lat));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lng",lng));
        actionPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

        HttpResponse dbResp = dbClient.execute(actionPost);
        HttpEntity ent = dbResp.getEntity();
        respTxt = EntityUtils.toString(ent).trim();

        Log.i("ShareCode", t + ", " + d + ", " + lat + ", " + lng);
        Log.i("ShareCode",respTxt);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("ShareCode", String.valueOf(e));
        respTxt = null;
    }

    return respTxt;
}
```

And my php code is:

```
<? //Receive post data
echo $t = $_POST['t'];
$d = $_POST['d'];
$l = $_POST['lat'];
$lo= $_POST['lng'];
```

Now, I'm don't know that is happening, 'cause always I get this response:

```
Notice: Undefined index: t in /home/iplaces/public_html/iplaces_url.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: d in /home/iplaces/public_html/iplaces_url.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: lat in /home/iplaces/public_html/iplaces_url.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: lng in /home/iplaces/public_html/iplaces_url.php on line 20
```

I hope you can help me, I getting a little stressed with this...

Comment: Show line 17 to 20 of your script. Which parameter did you add last?

Comment: The lines 17 to 20 are the lines in PHP code above. The last parameter I added was 'd'.

Comment: And you already tested again without the last added parameter? Why are you only echoing one parameter? Use isset($_POST['d']) to check if it is set and echo a message when not.

Comment: `Log.i("ShareCode", String.valueOf(e));` better change that to `Log.i("Exception", e.getMessage());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

it will send data into request object.

```
<? //Receive post data
echo $t = $_REQUEST['t'];
$d = $_REQUEST['d'];
$l = $_REQUEST['lat'];
$lo= $_REQUEST['lng'];
```